# Install Ubuntu and remove Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I am sick of the new Windows 8. I just want to get rid of it completely and run Ubuntu.

I have a live CD. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Ubuntu already?

If so, then you may have ability to remove Windows partitions and allocate their space for some Ubuntu partitions.

If not, then use Live CD and install Ubuntu on whole disk, or make partitions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Step 0 : Save all your important files on a USB stick or anything else, because all your data will be removed

Step 1 : Boot your computer on your Live Cd

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Step 2 : Choose "Install Ubuntu" on the desktop.

Step 3 : During the installation process, select the option below, which should remove everything and replace it by Ubuntu

[http://www.wikihow.com/Image:Install-Ubuntu-12.04-Step-7Bullet3.jpg](http://www.wikihow.com/Image%3aInstall-Ubuntu-12.04-Step-7Bullet3.jpg)

Good Luck !